# Actionscript 3 Air for Android DatePicker Ane

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, ane

I need a datepicker for my App build with Adobe Flash and AIR. I am using the following ANE (https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-DatePicker),but it does not show up a datepicker. Following is my code :

```
    function showDatePicker():void{
    var currentDate : Date = new Date();
    var callback : Function = function( selectedDate:String ) : void {
    trace("selected date = ", selectedDate.toString());
    }
    // Native extension call
    //dp = new AirDatePicker();
    dp = AirDatePicker.getInstance();
    trace(AirDatePicker.isSupported);
    if(AirDatePicker.isSupported){
    dp.displayDatePicker(currentDate, callback, new Rectangle(0,0,_width,_height));
    }else{
    //removeAllStuff();
    //gotoAndStop(1, "Home");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use distriqt's Dialog instead >:)
https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Dialog